# One line if-then without else clause

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, if-statement

I have the following piece of code that I am wondering if it can be condensed to one line:

```
if self.id
  return if Party.find_by_id(self.id).name.downcase == self.name.downcase
end
```

I was wondering if there is anyway to have this statement in one line.

I know you can use `if statement ? then_statement : else_statement` but hopefully you can see here that there is no else. Perhaps `break` or `continue` or something like that? (Feel free to make optimisation to the actual code if you see it - that's pretty much the purpose here)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple, just jam them together :)

```
return if self.id && Party.find_by_id(self.id).name.downcase == self.name.downcase
```

Comment: DOH! Totally wasn't thinking that... :D

Answer (score 1):

These are all equivalent:

```
if some_condition
    do_something
end

if some_condition; do_something; end

do_something if some_condition;

some_condition and do_something
```

But of course, your example already uses two of these variants :)